# Import 10 csv files and export as 10 worksheets of 1 xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have `10` `csv` files and want to save all the files as `10` worksheets of `1` `xlsx` file.

`data1.csv`,`data2.csv`,`.......`,`data10.csv`.

Attempt

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

all_datasets = pd.DataFrame()
for x in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(x)

# I want to export the corresponding csv files as 10 worksheets of 1 xlsx 

#initialze the excel writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_datasets_combinedworksheets.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


frames = {'sheetName_1': df1, 'sheetName_2': df2,
        'sheetName_3': df3,'sheetName_4': df4}

for sheet, frame in  frames.iteritems(): # .use .items for python 3.X
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet)

#critical last step
writer.save()
```

I'm open to other approach, please share your code, thanks in advance

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? Does it give you the output you expect?

Comment: unfortunately no. How would you attempt this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write dictionary of dataframes to separate excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209564/write-dictionary-of-dataframes-to-separate-excel-sheets)

Comment: my code is not working.. my approach is not efficient, I would prefer a more intuitive approach. The gap in my code is how do I export the csv files as individual dataframes so I can plug in the` pd.ExcelWriter` part to export the worksheets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're overwriting the variable `df` in every iteration of your loop.
2. You don't have any variables called `df1`, `df2` etc. but you're trying to use them to create your `frames` dictionary.
3. You never use `all_datasets`.

Try:

```
import os
frames = {f: pd.read_csv(f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".csv")}
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('all_datasets_combinedworksheets.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for sheet, frame in frames.items():
    frame.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I defined my `path` and set my working directory `os.chdir(path)` it works, However, I can't find the `all_datasets_combinedworksheets.xlsx` in my directory after running `os.getcwd()`

Comment: It works in the jupyter but the file `all_datasets_combinedworksheets.xlsx` is nowhere to be found in my directory

Comment: I found the issue, you left out the `writer.save()` in your code. Thanks